# Error: "The procedure entry point ?JPEG_convert_to_rgb@@YAPAEHPAEPAH1@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library libimage.dll"

Tags: c, nxopen, unigraphicsnx

Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005, C/C++, automation for Unigraphics NX using Open C

I'm trying to code an external program for NXOpen (i.e. a program with the NX library that runs on Windows, as opposed to an internal program that runs within NX). Right now I'm just testing to make sure the link structure is good, etc.

When I try to run the .exe that was generated, it does nothing for a few moments and then I get the following error: "The procedure entry point ?JPEG_convert_to_rgb@@YAPAEHPAEPAH1@Z could not be located in the dynamic link library libimage.dll"

I have nothing to go on and Googling so far has been vastly unhelpful.  The stuff on here seems to be file-specific for each case, and I'd never heard of this JPEG_convert_to_rgb before now.  What can I do to fix this?

Additional info: I'm not sure if I broke something when [trying to solve my last issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025888/error-this-application-failed-to-start-because-libufun-dll-was-not-found), or if this would have happened anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I called up GTAC.  The issue turned out to be quite specific to the NX library and I'm not even fully certain what happened.

Basically, I had some environment variables that needed to be set: TC_DATA and TC_ROOT, though for some people it will be IMAN_DATA and IMAN_ROOT.  These can be found if you open up NX through Teamcenter, go to Help->NX Log File, and do a ctrl-F to search for these terms.  There you should find what the variables should be set to, and then set them as that.  You should also make sure the UGII_BASE_DIR is set properly, and that your UGII_ROOT_DIR is at the beginning of your PATH variable.  Also: call %tc_data%\tc_profilevars to set the other TC variables; call %iman_data%\iman_profilevars to set the other IMAN variables.  There's also something else that I can't remember - this answer is not complete, it's just as complete as I can make it.

If this makes no sense to you, and you're using NX Open, you should probably call GTAC; if you can use an internal application instead of an external, you might be better off doing so.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are compiling a C header file in C++ and suffering from the C++ compiler mangling your names.  The DLL should export non-mangled names.  Try wrapping the include of the header file in an `extern "C"` block.

Comment: Turns out the issue was completely specific to the NX environment.  After becoming friends with the woman who answers the phone at GTAC for NXOpen issues, I finally sort of solved it.  Sort of.